# How to run a flutter app even though it is closed while using awesome notifications

Tags: flutter, background, awesome-notifications

I am using the awesome notifications and I want to notifications to be triggered even though the app is closed (possibly terminated). The notification should be triggered by a server. The type of server is sqflite and should be able to both send and receive data from the app.